# return response to caller and continue with other things

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have api method that looks something like this.
My question is if this is possible in some way. Without that the actually caller has to 
wait until
someotherFunction(); is done.

```
exports.callback = function (req, res) {  
  getValue()
   .then(function (result) {
      return res.send(200);
    })
   .catch(function () {
      return res.send(404);
   });

   //do other stuff here without holding up the response
   someotherFunction();

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

the return will not escape exports.callback because they are in a other function ... (a anonym function)

this:

```
getValue().then(function (result) {
  return res.send(200);
})
```

is only a methode u call with a function inside
normaly it looks like this without a function

```
 getValue().then(res.send(200))
```

so the return will place res.send(200) to getValue().then();

nothing more

so exports.callback will only return to his call after someotherFunction(); is done

Comment: thanks,
is there any other way i could accomplish something like that.
Meaning, after i return response trigger something else?

Comment: mmh lets see ... you can call someotherFunction with ajax, then retun your response, then u dont have to wait until someotherFunction is done

Comment: no, thats not a option. The callback is not triggerd by ajax call in the first place.
So the client has nothing to do with that callback.
I will dig into that problem more, thanks anyway!

Comment: so u should say why its importent that you send a response and then do someting... add that to your question, it could be the problem can be solved at a other point u thought